# MVC 3 Scaffolding Error when running Scaffold Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nuget, scaffolding, scaffold

I have installed MvcScaffolding without any issues but when I try to execute a scaffold request I get the error "DbContext.Task.t4" does not exist along with other files that are missing. I have a model called Task which I think its referring to but I am at a loss on how I fix this error?

> "Scaffold Controller Task -ModelType Task -ControllerName
>   TasksController -DbContextType TasksDbContext"

**Install-Package MvcScaffolding**

- PM> Install-Package MvcScaffolding
- Attempting to resolve dependency 'T4Scaffolding (≥ 1.0.2)'.
- Attempting to resolve dependency 'EntityFramework (≥ 4.1.10311.0)'.
- Successfully installed 'MvcScaffolding 1.0.2'.
- Successfully added 'MvcScaffolding 1.0.2' to MvcApplication1.

**Error**

- PM> Scaffold Controller Task -ModelType Task -ControllerName TasksController -DbContextType TasksDbContext

Scaffolding TasksController...

Find-ScaffolderTemplate : Could not find template 'DbContext.Task.t4' below folders ['C:\Development\MVCPLTaskmanager\MvcApplication1\packages\T4Scaffolding.1
.0.2\tools\EFDbContext']
At line:1 char:23
+ param($c, $a) return . <<<<  $c @a
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Find-ScaffolderTemplate], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : T4Scaffolding.Cmdlets.FindScaffolderTemplateCmdlet

Get-ProjectType : Cannot find a type matching the name 'MvcApplication1.Models.TasksDbContext'. Try specifying the fully-qualified type name, including namesp
ace.
At C:\Development\MVCPLTaskmanager\MvcApplication1\packages\T4Scaffolding.1.0.2\tools\EFDbContext\T4Scaffolding.EFDbContext.ps1:45 char:39
+     $foundDbContextType = Get-ProjectType <<<<  ($dbContextNamespace + "." + $DbContextType) -Project $Project
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ProjectType], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : T4Scaffolding.Cmdlets.GetProjectTypeCmdlet

Invoke-Scaffolder : Created database context TasksDbContext, but could not find it as a project item
At C:\Development\MVCPLTaskmanager\MvcApplication1\packages\MvcScaffolding.1.0.2\tools\Controller\MvcScaffolding.Controller.ps1:71 char:40
+         $dbContextScaffolderResult = Scaffold <<<<  DbContext -ModelType $foundModelType.FullName -DbContextType $DbContextType -Area $Area -Project $Projec
t -CodeLanguage $CodeLanguage -BlockUi
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-Scaffolder], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : T4Scaffolding.Cmdlets.InvokeScaffolderCmdlet

**ANSWER**
It turns out that my model's namespace needs to be the same as the MVC project. Once I changed the namespace the scaffolding worked.

Comment: Can you add the answer you have here as an answer below and accept it? This question is marked as unanswered in searches.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, but it was due to the model classes having errors in them, which caused them to not build.  Thus there was no model matching the name I gave to scaffolding and it concluded that I hadn't used the correct namespace.

So...

- Check your code for build errors
- Make sure the namespace of your Models is the namespace of your Application